docket login fails on kamal setup
In a rails v 8 app, running kamal setup results in this error
INFO [5402d41a] Running docker login -u [REDACTED] -p [REDACTED] as your_user@localhost
 Finished all in 0.1 seconds
Releasing the deploy lock...
 Finished all in 5.9 seconds
 ERROR (SSHKit::Command::Failed): docker exit status: 256
docker stdout: Nothing written
docker stderr: Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

The docker password  referenced in deploy.yml is stored as an environmental variable on the remote server.
# Credentials for your image host.
registry:
  # Specify the registry server, if you're not using Docker Hub
  # server: registry.digitalocean.com / ghcr.io / ...
  username: your_user

  # Always use an access token rather than real password when possible.
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

Remote server .bashrc
# kamal password
export KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD="dckr_pat_token"


The docker password  referenced in deploy.yml has to be stored as an environmental variable in the local machine.
